# cambiar formato de fecha PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, date

Cuando hago un INSERT en la bdd mediante un formulario una de las columnas me genera automáticamente la fecha en la que se ha realizado, el caso es que se almacena con este formato

```
2017-03-29 17:12:16
```

Lo que estoy tratando de resolver es cambiar el formato a **dd/mm/aaaa** a la hora de mostrarla por pantalla

Estoy usando phpMyAdmin para administrar la bdd, desde allí se puede modificar el formato? o tiene que ser mediante php? de ser este último caso como se podría hacer?

gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias hacerlo desde PHP y seria algo así:

```
$fecha = 2017-03-29 17:12:16;

$nueva_fecha = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fecha));
```

Answer (score 1):

O puedes cambiar el formato en la query al recoger los datos de la base de datos.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MI_FECHA,'%d/%m/%Y') AS FECHA FROM MI_TABLA;
```

Y ya muestras directamente el campo 'FECHA'.